# Split task in case of interruption: know when start, postpone finish based on interruptions

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, task-management, dependencies

I'm new in Microsoft Project & in the forum, so forgive me if my comment is just imposible to manage...

I have a team in which some of the members get continuous interruptions due to urgent customer's additional tasks, so, their planned tasks get heavily affected.

So far, I add the tasks at the end (new customer task) & get a resource conflict indication (the red man). To solve it, I Split the task & accommodate the new task in the proper timing. Solved.

The issue comes when the new task with higher priority takes longer tan expected, as I need to manually revise the planned splitted task.
This is quite repetitive & noisy... either for new urgent tasks & for delays happening.

**Question:** is there a way to make in the planned task 1 splitted a dependency on the new task 2 coming? So, when adding a new task 3 I can Split again the planned task 1, assign dependency of the new 'fraction' of the task to the new urgent task 3 & get automatically a new date for the planned task 1.

Sorry if the question is complicated, my life in Project planning is...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn’t this fundamentally trying to rebase your project plan to make interruptions look like they were planned? There’s an answer that tries to answer this from an MS Project POV, but I think it might be better to ask what you’re really trying to communicate about the state of the project when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. MSP does not allow assigning logical dependencies (i.e. links/relationships) to the split parts of split tasks.  To create such links, you must first break the task into two (or more) separate pieces (e.g. "Task Name - 0-50%" and "Task Name - 51-100%") that are linked together with FS+0 relationships.  Your question is a little unclear, so not sure this is what you want to do.
2. Manually splitting tasks (or breaking and re-linking tasks) to handle resource interruptions sounds pretty inefficient to me.  I would let the resource leveler handle it. After adding and scheduling the interruption task (typically with a SNET constraint), do the following.  First make sure the "Leveling can create splits in remaining work" leveling option is checked.  Then point to the red man for the task you want to interrupt, right click, and choose "Reschedule to Available Date." This tells the leveler to automatically edit the work assignment for the interrupted task - visually creating a split around the interruption and extending the task's finish date. Note1: this is for auto-scheduled tasks only. Note2: Any future leveling actions (e.g. the "Level Resource" or "Level All" buttons) may over-write this one-off change.